# Does Chrome Mobile on ICS support extensions?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, browser, chrome-for-android

I saw Google just released the beta for a mobile Chrome browser. They say they brought all the features over from the full browser, or at least they want to. Does anyone have an ICS device with the beta Chrome on it and can confirm if they support the extensions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not, and Flash is also not supported as of now. [Information Week reports](http://informationweek.com/news/development/open-source/232600414) (and I can personally corroborate):

> Web apps and extensions, including Adobe Flash Player, are not
>   supported in the initial release of Chrome for Android Beta.

Trying to visit the extensions Web Store page on my Xoom results in a page which simply says the following:

> Sorry, your operating system is not supported just yet. The Chrome Web
>   Store is available on Windows, Mac and Linux. Why don't you send a
>   reminder to yourself to try it out later?