# Google Chrome for Android: Chrome Web Store

Tags: chrome-for-android, samsung-galaxy-y

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Chrome Mobile on ICS support extensions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/does-chrome-mobile-on-ics-support-extensions)

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y and Google Chrome for Android is incompatible with my Phone, so I am not able to test it. Can someone tell me as to whether Chrome Web Store and its apps are available in Google Chrome for Android too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: no, Chrome extensions (which are packaged as .crx files as mentioned below) are not supported on Chrome for Android.

This is answered in detail by the Chrome Web Store FAQ:

> **Will apps work on Android?**
>
> If your app is pure HTML, CSS3, and JavaScript and is hosted on your servers there is a good chance that it will work in the browser on Android. However, .crx files (including packaged apps) are not supported on Android. Users cannot install their apps onto the Android browser, but they can most likely use those apps by directly accessing the app's URL.

https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq#faq-app-19